# Salesforce Integrations BETA compared to Mulesoft (or other) service bus

Tags: lightning, integration, webservices

I see in Spring '17 there is a new area in the LEX Setup menu called Integrations (BETA).  I'm reviewing the documentation but I don't know much about microservices nor how they relate to SFDC.  Is this new functionality that could replace a service bus or is it somehow limited in some capacity?

Comment: Microservices would more likely apply to Heroku or Lightning Out.

Comment: Some basic document : http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/ext-svc-overview.pdf